# Is there a way to create new files in Astro FM

Tags: text-editor, astro-file-manager

Astro File Manager has a text file editor built right in. Is there a way to create new text files in the app and edit them directly in it?

I am not looking for other apps (I know they exist) - specifically if and how it can be done in Astro File Manager (or the Pro version if that has the feature).

I should clarify - I mean plain text - not rtf/doc or something.

Comment: In folder view can't you click Menu and select New?

Comment: Gives me a new directory, but not new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking through the Help file and through Astro quite a bit, alas, I believe the answer is no. While it does allow for editing, the only option for creation is Directory (Folder) creation, as you pointed out.

That being said, I think this would be an excellent feature, and might be worth [suggesting to the developers](http://support.metago.net/entries/20454741-suggest-topics-or-new-categories-here).

I know you said you didn't want other apps, but to show one directly with the feature...

this is [X-plore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en)
[image]

Comment: While not quite it - this is a really well put together answer. I will examine X-plore FM as perhaps an alternative, and hopefully it will run on my device (a little underpowered as Android devices go). I will also make the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy an existing (save a blank master somewhere easy to remember) and edit that.  A little cumbersome, but effective.

Answer (score -2):

well, astro is not designed to do so.
should you need to create / edit docs, you had better go for other apps, i.e. quick office pro, docs2go, etc.

Comment: Text editor != Word Processor